# how does the compiler treat extending a record

Tags: f#

Does the compiler create a new location in memory when a record is extended (deep copy?) or does the compiler make the record mutable and modify the value?

For example:

```
type MyRecord = { A : string
                ; B : string
                }

let record = { A = "A"; B = "B" }

let record = { record with A = "new A" } //copy or overwrite?
```

Since I am overwriting `record` does the compiler copy or overwrite? Are there performance concerns either way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes the copy.

[Copy-and-update Record expression](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997059)

*A copy-and-update record expression elaborates as if it were a record expression written as follows:

**let v = expr in { field-label1 = expr1 ; … ; field-labeln = exprn; F1 = v.F1; ... ; FM = v.FM }**

where F1 ... FM are the fields of R that are not defined in field-initializers and v is a fresh variable.*

Answer (score 2):

This

```ml
type T = {
  A : string
  B : string
}

let x = { A = "a"; B = "b" }
let y = { x with A = "aa" }
```

is equivalent to this

```cs
class T {
    public readonly string A;
    public readonly string B;
    public T(string a, string b) {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

var x = new T("a", "b");
var y = new T("aa", x.B);
```